# How to stop "bounce back" in kivy ScrollEffect?

Tags: scroll, kivy

I have a long list of items that won't fit into the screen.  I want to be able to scroll through them, and NOT have the scroll bounce-back to the top when I release the mouse button.

I have looked into a number of potential solutions on this in this forum.  They all revolve around using effect_cls = 'ScrollEffect'.  But, that seems to prevent the screen from scrolling at all.

When I allow the default behavior ("DampedScroll"), it scrolls . . but then bounces back to the top.

When I set effect_cls = 'ScrollEffect', it doesn't allow scrolling at all.

There's some reference to being able to subclass the ScrollEffect and play with the parameters . . but I've not had any success with that.

Anyone out there had any better luck?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 5):

Well, if anyone is interested, I figured out the answer.  Quite simple.

I needed to add the following to the grid layout:
height: self.minimum_height

Then everything was fine.